# Some programs in XFCE load with the GNOME 3 default window decorations

Tags: xfce

As you can see in the following image, some apps load with the GNOME window decorations.[image]

I do not understand why this happens. How can I help this?
I'm using XFCE 4.16 in Arch Linux

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this environment variable anywhere you want:

`GTK_CSD=0`

It disables client-side window decorations for GTK3 based applications.

Or install gtk3-nocsd: https://github.com/PCMan/gtk3-nocsd

Comment: But, judging by the screenshots on gtk3-nocsd's GitHub page, it looks like they add the title bar of your window manager of choice, but the awful GTK 3 decoration just remains underneath. That is not very useful because it still steals vertical screen real estate. Isn't there a way to disable it completely?